# How to define column width at Formeo FornBuilder?

Tags: jquery, formbuilder

I started at a project with the OpenSource-Software [Formeo](https://draggable.github.io/formeo/). Formeo is from developer Kevin Chappell, who also created the similar [FormBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/). Formeo is a new development based on the FormBuilder. All normal functions are pretty well. Thanks for that, Kevin!

Unfortunately, i can not select the width of the columns (demo or in my local project). Nothing is suggested with the dropdown.

Is there a bug fix for here? In the documentation you can see a small preview where this still works.

**Demo from Doc:**
[image]

**Online-Demo:**
[image]

- https://github.com/Draggable/formeo
- https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have now understood the procedure and have been able to determine that it is not a bug in the software. The problem was sitting in front of the screen again :-).

It goes like this (as in the example above):

1. First insert three elements of the "Text Input" type. These are placed one below the other.
2. Now you have to move the element with the move-icon.
   **Note:** *There are two move icons. Left and at the top of the element. We use the upper icon here.*
3. If all three elements are placed next to each other, you can click the "edit icon" in the left element menu.
4. You can now change the width of the columns.